# Circuits explained without analogies

Tags: voltage, current, ohms-law, kirchhoffs-laws

So, I am trying to fully understand circuits without the use of analogies like "voltage is like a waterfall" or "a battery is like a pump," since I've heard that those analogies break down when we get to more complex circuits. I am looking to understand EXACTLY what is happening on the atomic and subatomic levels. So, I have a few questions.

1. When voltage is referred to as "potential difference," does that just mean a difference in potential energy per charge between two points?
2. What exactly causes a voltage?
3. (This is more of a series of questions) What exactly are the electrons doing as they are moving? The Drude model treats electrons and atoms like solid objects, with the electrons hitting the atoms like a game of Plinko. But is that what ACTUALLY happens? Furthermore, are electrons ripped from their atoms and hop around from electron orbital to electron orbital, or are they freely spread out in the metal? When moving, do they physically hit the atoms? I can't imagine they would hit the nucleus of the atoms if the nucleus is extremely small and far away from the electron cloud, so how could it be possible that they actually hit the atoms? My textbook shows this photo, which is the cause of my confusion. If the electrons DON'T physically collide with the atoms, what accounts for heat in a wire? If heat is a measure of the kinetic energy of the atoms, and if the electrons do not in fact physically collide with the atoms, where do the atoms get their extra kinetic energy that we feel as heat?

[image: Textbook photo]

4. With regards to Kirchoff's Voltage Law, I understand that all voltage drops = all voltage gains in a loop. That makes perfect sense as the law of conservation of energy. However, what I don't quite understand is when it is applied to a loop with just resistors, like the one below. If we go in a loop and sum up all the voltage gains and voltage drops, we should get 0. But I thought resistors only dissipate energy, thus the voltage gains should be 0 in the loop since a resistor can not provide voltage, and therefore, the voltage drops should also be 0, but they are not.
   [image: Kirchoff's Voltage Law]
5. Why does V = IR? If, for example, I were to use the analogy of water moving downwards through a hole in the bottom of a tube, moving that tube up and down in space should not increase the rate at which the water exits the hole. The gravitational "voltage" is increasing since height is increasing, but the current should (I think) stay the same in this scenario. So, why does more voltage mean more current?

[image: Water tanks at different heights]

I know these questions are basic, but I really want to fully understand EXACTLY how this stuff works.

---

Comment: `I am looking to understand EXACTLY what is happening on the atomic and subatomic levels`... you need to enroll in a university physics course

Comment: `same flow regardless of height` ... not the elevation of the container ... the height of the column of water (how full is the container)

Comment: So you want to "fully understand circuits without the use of analogies"?! You'll be surprised. Basically **everything** in physics is just a model or metaphoric description; this becomes even more true if you go to "atomic and subatomic levels". Note: ["Essentially, all models are wrong, but some are useful" (George Box)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong)

Comment: even though there are people who have this knowledge you are asking too much. Take a book from the library and read chapter 1 about charges. Many of these questions will be answered.

Comment: I second that. But to understand what voltage is it's better to start with charge (and static electricity), and to understand what current is you extend your newly gained knowledge to moved charge.

Comment: You might also want to ask yourself **why** you need this knowledge. I'm an EE so you might expect me to be able to describe what happens on a sub-atomic level. Well, I can't and I don't need to. For my daily work it is sufficient to see current as moving electrons and voltage as the force moving the electrons (or not moving when there's no current). Yes, a simple model but it does the job for me. So what is your goal making you need to know this. Forget about "exact" and focus on **what you need**.

Comment: I voted to close this as too broad but also upvoted because " I've heard that those analogies break down when we get to more complex circuits". But seriously, this is super broad.

Comment: Seems mostly ok until point 4, the drops with respect to your arrow are opposite for R2 compared to R3 and R4. So they sum to zero. On point 5 there is no such thing a voltage at a point, it is potential difference (voltage across / between two points). You are lifting the top and the bottom of the bucket tube device, there for the pressure difference / potential difference does not change.

Comment: This question belongs to Physics stack exchange. As far as an EE engineer, these things are less important. But I have to say that the greatest scientists are the ones who know what is going on deep within.

Comment: You can refer to "Physics" by Halliday Resnick and start with Electrostatics. I read it during my school days to understand everything related to charges. Once that foundation is set, it is easy to understand circuits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See 2.
2. A potential difference is much like potential energy in mechanics: The higher you are, the more "kinetic energy" you could *potentially* have.

This is the same for electrons. They will feel a force in the presence of an electric field, which could *potentially* cause them to gain kinetic energy:

\$\vec{F} = q\cdot \vec{E}\$

Similarly, they will also feel a force in the presence of a magnetic field. This is where analogies typically break down with most mechanics-based attempts. The total force on an electron was found by Mr. Lorentz (Lorentz force):

\$\vec{F} = q\cdot \vec{E} + q\cdot(\vec{v} \times\vec{B})\$

The potential is defined similarly to the potential energy in mechanics if we're not taking the magnetic field \$\vec{B}\$ into account.

\$\Phi=-\int_C\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}\$

(Compare this to the potential energy in mechanics: \$U=-\int_C\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}\$).

A voltage potential can only be calculated between two points in space, and so can only ever be a "difference". There is no "absolute voltage", only voltage differences. To make things easier we often choose a point in space (in the circuit) which we call ground (0V) though.

3. If you want to discuss what they are really doing, then you're up for a real treat. To discuss that, you need to dive into the world of quantum physics.

A short explanation could be that electrons gain and lose energy all the time. Heat is but one way to lose energy (through phonons). In LED for example, most of the electrons will lose their energy through photons! How electrons lose energy is strongly dependent on the material. For resistors this is pretty much only through phonons (sound waves/wiggles or heat), which is a form of electromagnetic radiation.

4. As stated in the first and second answer, the potential is defined as integrating over a line between two points:

\$\Phi_{AB}=-\int_A^B\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}\$

If there is *no varying magnetic field*, then it does not matter which path you take from A to B, the potential will stay identical. So if A and B are **the same point** you can just take a 0-length path which will give you a 0-potential. So that means you *have* to end up with 0, regardless of the path you take! If you take the path through all the resistors, it doesn't matter what the voltages do, they have to add up to 0 to not violate the laws of physics.

5. Depending on the material, a number of electrons can make it through the contacts. This depends among other things on how many free electrons are available in the material. For a very small piece of uniform material, the current can be formulated using a current density:

\$\vec{J}=\sigma\cdot \vec{E}\$

For metals, there are a lot of free electrons, so not much electric field is necessary to move these free electrons! For semiconductors, it depends on how many free charge carriers there are, which in turn depends on doping. Isolators, will conduct pretty much no current because they have little to no free electrons.

Ohm's law is just the same formula for a larger piece of uniform material. If the same voltage is applied across a longer piece of material, the electric field will become smaller (\$|\vec{E}|=V_R/l\$) and so will the current. If the material is made wider, then more current can pass through the bigger area (\$I=A\cdot |\vec{J}|\$).

Answer (score 7):

You don't want analogies *since I've heard that those analogies break down when we get to more complex circuits.*

Yes, the models fall apart, just like Newtonian physics don't work when you get to light speed.  However most things don't work at light speed thus for 99% of the cases the model is fine.

The same holds for electronics. 99.99% of the time I do not use the characteristics of an NPN transistor. All I use is an estimated gain and "it starts conducting somewhere around Vbe = 0.6Volts".

Another example: when I was young I bought an expensive 6.5 digit multimeter because I thought I needed it. Nowadays I solve 9 out of 10 problems with a five dollar 3.5 digit multimeter. (The other 10% require a scope).

Bottom line: start learning the basics. You will not need the quantum mechanics of how semiconductors work for another 10 years.

Comment: Yes even the latest quantum / relativistic models are wrong, however they may always be used (most of the time), if they are simpler than what replaces them.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a boring answer, but everything is an analogy. The closest you get to "what is really happening" is the mathematics. And even that is an analogy/description and not "the truth".

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid analogies then your question itself is flawed.
You want to know what a voltage source is **exactly**? Then state which voltage source you're talking about: a lead-acid battery, solar panel, dynamo, alternator, Lipo battery,.... They **all** work fundamenntally different but they can also all be represented with a single analogy with regard to the voltage source.

The same goes if your talking about semiconductors or capacitors. There can be several different mechanisms (e.g. MOSFET versus BJT, ceramic versus electyrolyte capacitor to name just a few).

Is this your goal? Do you really want to learn bottom-up in this case instead of grabbing the fundamentals first with a top-down approach?

Furthermore, analogies and abstraction actually work in your advantage if you accept them. As an example: both thermal and mechanical problems can be perfectly modelled with electronic models. This happens in professional environments on a daily basis.